# R save variable by string name

Tags: r

I want to name a variable by a string name.

```
variable_name=paste0("name",4,sep="")
assign(variable_name,55)
save(get(variable_name),file="file_name")
```

I got error msg: object ‘get(name)’ not found

but if I do

```
save(variable_name,file="file_name")
```

I only saved the string variable_name, which is "name 4" in this case.

How do I save the name4=55 as a file?

Comment: `variable_name` doesn't equal 55, `name 4` does

Comment: Also, I suggest `paste0` vs `paste`. As written, you assign to `name 4`, requiring back-ticks for usage. This is generally a bad practice for variable names

Comment: You want `save(list = variable_name, file = "file_name")`, and please take Alex's advice.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex and @ Richard!